# Adding PowerShell functions to an object

Tags: function, variables, object, powershell

I have a PowerShell module with a group of functions.

The function createService creates an instance of a service and returns a variable. Several of my functions use the returned value, but I only want one instance of the service so I cannot call createService in each function.

On the command line, I can do `$var = createService($string)`, then call `update($var)` and it will work properly, but I don't want to force the user to remember to use `$var` as a parameter.

Is there a way to put these functions in an object/class so the variable can be stored globally and referenced inside each function instead of through parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to start the service by the exposed functions, so that a user does even have to care of starting it.

```
$module = {
    # The only service instance, $null so far
    $script:service = $null

    # Starts the service once and keeps its the only instance
    function Start-MyService {
        if ($null -eq $script:service) {
            "Starting service"
            $script:service = 'MyService'
        }
    }

    # Ensures the service by Start-MyService and then operates on $script:service
    function Update-MyService1 {
        Start-MyService
        "Updating service 1: $script:service"
    }

    # Ensures the service by Start-MyService and then operates on $script:service
    function Update-MyService2 {
        Start-MyService
        "Updating service 2: $script:service"
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Function Update-MyService1, Update-MyService2
}

$null = New-Module $module

# Starting service
# Updating service 1: MyService
Update-MyService1

# Updating service 2: MyService
Update-MyService2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your module, if you assign the service object to a script scoped variable, all functions in the module can access the variable. Here is an example:

```
$module = {
    function StartNewService {
        $script:service = 'MyService'
    }
    function UpdateService {
        "Updating service: " + $script:service
    }
    Export-ModuleMember -Function StartNewService, UpdateService
}

$null = New-Module $module

# StartNewService creates the service variable.
StartNewService
# UpdateService accesses the service variable created by StartNewService.
UpdateService
```

If you declare the variable as `$global:service`, you can access the variable from outside the module as well.

**Edit:** To address the comments below, here is a more practical example that shows an appropriate situation for sharing a variable among functions in a module. In this case all of the functions in the module depend on the same instance of the `$Locations` variable. In this example the variable is created outside of the functions, and is kept private by not including it in the `Export-ModuleMember` command.

Here is a simplified version of my LocationName.psm1

```
$Locations = @{}

function Save-LocationName {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
    $Locations[$Name] = $PWD
}

function Move-LocationName {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
    if($Locations[$Name]) {
        Set-Location $Locations[$Name]
    }
    else {
        throw ("Location $Name does not exist.")
    }
}

New-Alias -Name svln -Value Save-LocationName
New-Alias -Name mvln -Value Move-LocationName

Export-ModuleMember -Function Save-LocationName, Move-LocationName -Alias svln, mvln
```

With this module a user can give a name to a directory, and move to that location by using the given name. For example if I am at `\\server01\c$\Program Files\Publisher\Application\Logs`, I can save the location by entering `svln logs1`. Now if I change my location, I can return to the logs directory with `mvln logs1`. In this example it would be impractical to use the locations hashtable for input and output since the functions are always working with the same instance.

Comment: I discourage implementation of functions that operate on the reliance of shared hidden data like this. If a function should return a value that another should operate on, they should support pipelining. So one function should be `New-Service` which could be piped to `Start-Service` or `Set-Service`. `New-Service` should return an object type that can be piped to the other functions.

Comment: @AndyArismendi Generally I agree, but there are valid cases for sharing variables among functions when using `Modules`.

Comment: Since these functions are being exported to the module customer they should adhere to cmdlet standard behavior. If update-service is called first it will obviously yield an desirable result.

Comment: Meant to say "undesirable" result.

Comment: It might not be an undesirable result; we don't know what the OP's implementation of `update-service` is. I've updated my answer with a practical example where I think it is appropriate to have a shared variable.